# System wide DAO level exception mapping to Http Status codes in Spring MVC 3.1

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, exception

Is there anyway to map Spring exceptions (eg. [JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException.html)) to REST status code without using a controller specific `@ExceptionHandler`? I would like to configure that system wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) to catch specific exception types. Another possible strategy is to use a generic or abstract DAO class which implements the `@ExceptionHandler` handlers.